# Best way for web app to listen to server events

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, websocket, architecture

I am implementing a restaurant application and I want for the restaurant app to be able to continuously listen for new orders. I've investigated server side events and websockets and I don't understand what is better and how can I achieve to have a web page that continously listens for server updates (without making too many request because I want to deploy and not be charged enormously for the number of requests).

My current thought is to have server side events that once per 10 seconds returns the list of new orders. This would mean that I have one undie-ing request that get processed on the UI. Is this the best approach? How does Uber Eats implement the current order event in which the user is continously updated on the order status?

Comment: This is difficult to answer without knowing what the volume of requests for orders are. Feel free to provide more information. Is this for school, enterprise?

Comment: Apache has built a WSS solution. If it were me, I'd use this as a platform to do your communication. I'm doing something along these lines with Ratchet

Comment: I'd suggest just implementing your solution with a tomcat server rather than use websocket and all that. Just have another servlet listening on whatever port. Don't roll your own. Too many issues you'd need to resolve.